# PostgreSQL indexes and replication techniques

Tags: postgresql, indexing, database-replication

Background: so far I've always used Django with its ORM to build small websites, so which database (MySQL vs PostgreSQL) was doing all the work behind the curtains wasn't really an issue.

Recently I decided to learn more about the differences between those two. I've just finished reading this (long) [article](https://eng.uber.com/mysql-migration/) which explores how indexes work in PostgresSQL and I am really shocked about the following fact:

> "For instance, if we have a table with a dozen indexes defined on it, an update to a field that is only covered by a single index must be propagated into all 12 indexes to reflect the ctid for the new row."

I'm not an expert at all, but sounds insane to me that such an overload should happen *by design* when updating fields not involved in an index.

Moreover, the article goes on explaining how PostgreSQL replication strategy does not work at logical level, but at on-disk level, i.e. the master sends to the slaves a list (byte by byte) of all changes to apply on the disk rather than more abstract instructions such as `UPDATE <fields> ON <table> WHERE ...`.

Although many short articles on the web comparing MySQL and PostgreSQL generally tend to claim that PostgreSQL is technically more advanced (ACID, JSON support, etc..), these two problems seem to be serious drawback to me. Can you confirm those statements and possibly point out further resources about these issues?

Thank you.

Comment: The article in question caused quite a stir in the Postgres community; as a result, several prominent community members have responded to these criticisms in exhaustive detail (e.g. [here](https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/thoughts-on-ubers-list-of-postgres-limitations/), [here](http://use-the-index-luke.com/blog/2016-07-29/on-ubers-choice-of-databases), [here](http://rhaas.blogspot.com.au/2016/08/ubers-move-away-from-postgresql.html), [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5dIbB5GIqAo)).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### About indexes and performance

It is certainly true that PostgreSQL has to do more work on indexes when a row is updated. This is due to the fact that an [`UPDATE` actually creates a new row version](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/routine-vacuuming.html#VACUUM-FOR-SPACE-RECOVERY) in the table, and the indexes have to point to that new row version.

There is, however, a way to mitigate the impact: if you set [`fillfactor`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-STORAGE-PARAMETERS) to less than 100, so that there is free space in the data pages, and no indexed column is updated, PostgreSQL can create a [“heap only tuple”](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob;f=src/backend/access/heap/README.HOT), and such a *HOT update* will not need to touch any index.

MySQL's InnoDB with its [secondary indexes (that reference the primary key index)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-index-types.html) has to do less work updating indexes. You pay the price for that with every index scan: first, you have to scan the secondary index to find the primary key, then you have to scan the primary key index to find the table row.

So there is a trade-off, but I think it is one-sided to unconditionally say that one solution is better.

### About replication

MySQL has had a replication solution much earlier than PostgreSQL. It uses the *binary log* for replication, which is a slightly deceptive name as it actually contains SQL statements.

Version 9.0 of PostgreSQL introduced *streaming replication*, which ships the transaction log to the standby. This information is on the physical level, so primary and standby are kept physically identical. This is often more wasteful than shipping SQL statements (index updates!), but it is a very stable solution that leaves no room for replication conflicts.

PostgreSQL v10 has introduced *logical replication*, which generates an abstract description of the change, similar to an SQL statement. This allows for more flexible replication scenarios.

So the article you are referencing has become somewhat outdated in this respect.